# How do I remove this GoTo?

Tags: vb.net

I am curious if it is possible to parse an input box for a data type and if it does not match the data type it will loop until the correct type is done. I understand how to do this with ranges but would rather not if it is possible.

The code I have is:

```
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim amountAssignments As Integer
    Dim pointsEarned As Integer = 0
    Dim pointsEarnedTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim pointsPossible As Integer = 0
    Dim pointsPossibleTotal As Integer = 0
    Dim Assignment As Integer = 1

    Integer.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, amountAssignments)

    Do Until Assignment > amountAssignments
        txtAmount.Text = String.Empty
        pointsEarned = Integer.Parse(InputBox("Please enter the amount, as a whole number, of Points Earned for Assignment " & Assignment & ":"))
        On Error GoTo Check
        pointsEarnedTotal = pointsEarnedTotal + pointsEarned
        pointsPossible = Integer.Parse(InputBox("Please enter the amount, as a whole number, of Points Possible for Assignment " & Assignment & ":"))
        On Error GoTo Check
        pointsPossibleTotal = pointsPossibleTotal + pointsPossible
        Assignment = Assignment + 1
    Loop

    lblGrade.Text = (pointsEarnedTotal / pointsPossibleTotal)
Check:
    MessageBox.Show("An error has occured, most likely due to an improper value in the points earned or possible box. Please try running the program again with proper values.", "Please run the program again", _
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)

End Sub
```

I know that GoTo isn't a "right" or preferred solution but I used that more as a temporary place holder. Any help would be appreciated as this is beyond my programming abilities currently.

Comment: add exception handlers - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk6t46tz.aspx

Comment: you can use a break statement...

Comment: `On Error Goto` in VB.NET? Is that even still supported? :-(

Comment: Move code after `check:` label into its own sub-routine. Invoke the sub-routine on error and `break` out of the loop. Also, use `Integer.TryParse` to check if a string can be converted to an int.

Comment: @Matteo sadly, [yes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx)

Comment: The funny (or not so funny) thing about using poor coding practices as a 'temporary place holder' is that they sometimes seem to find their way in to production code!

Comment: Note that this existing `On Error GoTo` code is wrong within itself. If you did want to continue using it without changing to exceptions you'd need to add `On Error GoTo 0` after the statements you wanted to "catch" errors in.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider using Integer.TryParse for all of  your conversions instead of Parse that way it will allow you to test whether or not the conversion failed without throwing and error. Something like this should work

```
If Integer.TryParse(txtAmount.Text, amountAssignments) Then
    Do Until Assignment > amountAssignments
        txtAmount.Text = String.Empty
        If Not Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Please enter the amount, as a whole number, of Points Earned for Assignment " & Assignment & ":"), pointsEarned) Then
            showError()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        pointsEarnedTotal = pointsEarnedTotal + pointsEarned
        If Not Integer.TryParse(InputBox("Please enter the amount, as a whole number, of Points Possible for Assignment " & Assignment & ":"), pointsPossible) Then
            showError()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        pointsPossibleTotal = pointsPossibleTotal + pointsPossible
        Assignment = Assignment + 1
    Loop
    lblGrade.Text = (pointsEarnedTotal / pointsPossibleTotal)
Else
    showError()
End If
```

Where your messagebox has been put in a Subroutine like this.

```
Sub showError()
    MessageBox.Show("An error has occured, most likely due to an improper value in the points earned or possible box. Please try running the program again with proper values.", "Please run the program again", _
     MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am curious if it is possible to parse an input box for a data type
>   and if it does not match the data type it will loop until the correct
>   type is done.

Call a function that retries itself if [Integer.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) fails.

```
Private Function AskInteger(prompt As String) As Integer
    Dim result As Integer
    If Not Integer.TryParse(InputBox(prompt), result) Then
        MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred...")
        Return AskInteger(prompt)
    End If
    Return result
End Function
```

This will continue until the parse succeeds and finally return the integer, so it can be safely called without error checking:

```
pointsEarned = AskInteger("Please enter the amount...")
```

Comment: Why would you want a recursive solution for this problem? Just use a do ... loop.

Comment: @MatteoItalia I just thought it was more concise, because a loop would need to explicitly check the result of TryParse twice (if not valid display error message ... loop until valid).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, replace each and every `On Error GoTo` you have with a Try-Catch statement or at least use a function instead of a GoTo! Using GoTo at all is a very bad practice. It will be a big pain especially later on when you come back to update something or if someone else tries to read the code it will be very hard. See: http://forums.devshed.com/showpost.php?p=2605339&postcount=3 and http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/programming-with-reason-why-is-goto-bad/228200966.

Here is a little enhanced version of nmclean's answer

```
Private Function GetInput(ByVal prompt As String, ByVal NumOfRetries As Integer) As Integer
    Try
        Return Integer.Parse(InputBox(prompt))
    Catch ex As Exception
        If NumOfRetries > 0 Then
            NumOfRetries -= 1
            Return GetInput(prompt, NumOfRetries)
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

And of course, to run this function use `Dim theInt As Integer = GetInput("123", 5)`.

Mark Hall, don't you think making the whole chunk of code you gave into a function whould be better? Like I did. That would save some lines of code.

Comment: Your example call does not supply a value for the NumOfRetries parameter so it will not compile as that value is not optional.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Just fixed it. :)